# Page_Load event fires only once

Tags: asp.net, events

I have an asp.net website that has a master page and multiple normal pages. There's a menu bar on the master page that enables the user to select the normal page. I have code in the Page_Load event of one of the normal pages. Problem is, this event seems to trigger only once - the first time the user navigates to the page. If the user navigates to another page and then back again, the event doesn't fire. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is the page cached in the browser? If so, it will not get loaded from the server again and your `page_load` will not get fired.

Comment: Depending on your IIS settings there's a good chance the page is being cached by the browser and not making the roundtrip back to the server. (Especially true if navigating to the previous page using the back button). What happens when you add a unique QueryString variable to the end of the URL? `somepage.aspx --> somepage.aspx?2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that problem was caused by the browser caching the page, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

The problem appears not only when using the back button so I'm afraid guarding against this doesn't solve the problem.

My solution has been to replace the simple html hyperlinks I used for the menu with server side asp.net button controls. When the code behind executes a response.redirect the page_load event of the target page seems to be executed each time.

Comment: Actually, I found a better way. Simply adding the following to the page_load event prevents the page from being cached:     Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

Answer (score 1):

If user user `Back` Button of browser browser will use cached version of your pages if your pages are normal and no specific setting applied to them. these codes cause if user use `Back` button nothing show to him/her:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)) ;
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false) ;
Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches) ;
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache) ;
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Or for prvent user to go back use this code:

```
<body onLoad="if(history.length>0)history.go(+1)">
```